# Codeigniter and .htaccess file to ignore index.php

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

So I'm having a weird problem with .htaccess file and codeigniter. I have a wamp server on my local machine and there it works as expected. I have folders like that wamp/www/my_app and in my_app folder i have .htaccess file like that:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /my_app/
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
   ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

And in mine config.php gile i have:

```
 $config['base_url']='';
 $config['index_page']='';
 $config['uri_protocol']='AUTO';
```

So i tried uploading that project to debian server on link like apps.myserver.com/my_app. I put my app to folder var/www/my_app. But the trick is that it doesn't work.

I have tried changing uri_protocol to all 5 options but no change. I also tried putting .htaccess file to var/www instead of var/www/my_app but no change either.

I keep getting that stupid 404 Not Found error when i try to access controlers without index.php prefix.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I checked phpinfo on server and found that mod_rewrite is in loaded modules.

Comment: first check mod_rewrite is enabled on your server, send remove this ErrorDocuemnt from top and bottom and just comment out RewriteBase and check

Comment: So i comment out all lines except lines number 3 and 7 and nothing happens. Does it mean i don't have rewrite module on server or does it mean it doesn't read my .htaccess file?

Comment: this is minimum htaccess code on CI document RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: I tried exactly the code u gave me but no effect, and i checked so i can confirm that mod_rewrite is loaded on server.

Comment: if you have wamp server just type localhost on browser you will phpinfo() link click on it find mod_rewrite under loaded modules if not loaded then you have to enable it in you wamp server and its really easy

Comment: Did u read my question? I said that mod_rewrite is enabled and i also said that it works well on wamp.

Answer (score 0):

The mod_rewrite module can have a couple different extensions. Your Debian server might use `mod_rewrite.so` instead of `mod_rewrite.c`.

That said, if you know mod_rewrite is enabled, and your application isn't being widely distributed and needs to check for it, you can safely eliminate the `if` checks.

You mentioned commenting out everything except lines 3 and 7 -- you commented out the `RewriteBase` definition, which broke stuff.

Try something simple, and work from there:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my_app/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Also, one variation you can do if an .htaccess is being weird, is to change everything after `index.php` to a query string. Note the `?` here:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

You may or may not to change the `uri_protocol` config setting in CodeIgniter. My guess is you specifically won't, but it's info for others who are having .htaccess issues.

Comment: Ok i tried all sugested options but no effect. I'm realy loosing it on that one :S